# Sanitization and Validations for Sails JS

Tags: node.js, validation, sails.js, sanitization

I'm using sails js 0.11. Are the inputs using `req.body` or `req.params.all()` sanitized? If not, what should be done to sanitize them?

Secondly, for validations - where can the validations be done? Eg: `req.params.all().id` should be an integer type.

Comment: you can use some sort of JSON schema validators, for example: [https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv]

Answer (score 0):

For sanitazing you can write [hook](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks) or service

Validation rules should be described in your [models](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations)